# Where do I find resourceIds of WebAPIs listed in Azure API access?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

ResourceId for Graph API is: https://graph.windows.net/

I found this in some sample code online, but couldn't find for other APIs. Where do I find resourceIds for other APIs like: Office 365 Management APIs, Windows Azure Active Directory, Windows Azure Service Management API

Answer (score 1):

Well, Microsoft Graph API is `https://graph.microsoft.com` as you might expect.

You can find a few for some Azure APIs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-msi#azure-services-that-support-azure-ad-authentication.

Ultimately if you cannot find it anywhere, you can use the Graph Explorer https://aka.ms/ge to get all service principals in your tenant via /beta/servicePrincipals.
Find the principal for the API and it'll have the identifier URI.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to find the API reference, look into some sample APIs in the doc. E.g. for `Office 365 Management APIs`, google the `Office 365 Management APIs reference`, we could find the docs like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference), so the `ResourceId` should be `https://manage.office.com`.

Use the same way, we could find `Windows Azure Active Directory(i.e. azure ad graph api)` is `https://graph.windows.net`, `Windows Azure Service Management API` is `https://management.core.windows.net`.